# Main SO offers meta review queues

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, top-bar

Today I noticed that dropdown list of review queues started to show Meta Reviews, that are not accessible to me because of reputation requirements. I think that button just should not be shown(as it was before).
 [image]

Comment: It should probably be shown *if you actually have access* to them. Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304951/295232

Comment: There is probably no need to show it at all. It's not like these  queue's have such a back log. I checked the amount of reviews being done today: 10 on close votes, 4 on reopen votes and 0 on suggested edits. At the same time the queue's are cleared....

Comment: @Luuklag that is because MSO is so active that it gets seen regularly.  But it might make sense for smaller sites that don't get nearly as much meta traffic

Comment: I thought the exact same thing